# API Post Prestashop in python

Tags: python, api, rest, post, prestashop-1.7

i try to create a product name in my script "apexxxxxlgenddssssss" and price "19.99"
but when i run script i get error 500. i check my log and i have nothing.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Connection parameters to the webservice
api_url = 'http://localhost/api'
api_key = 'my key'

# Resource to retrieve the empty schema
resource = 'products'
schema_param = 'schema=blank'

# Build the URL for the GET request to the empty schema
url = f'{api_url}/{resource}?{schema_param}&ws_key={api_key}'

# Send the GET request to retrieve the empty schema
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Load the XML content from the response
    xml_content = response.text

    # Parse the XML content
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_content)

    # Find the "name" element with language ID 1
    name_element = root.find(".//name/language[@id='1']")
    # Find the "price" element
    price_element = root.find(".//price")

    # Add content to the "name" element
    name_element.text = "apexxxxxlgenddssssss"
    # Add content to the "price" element
    price_element.text = "19.99"

    # Convert the XML tree to a string
    modified_xml = ET.tostring(root, encoding="unicode")

    # Convert the string to UTF-8 encoding
    modified_xml = modified_xml.encode('utf-8')

    # Display the modified XML content
    print(modified_xml.decode('utf-8'))

    # URL to create a new product
    create_url = f'{api_url}/{resource}?ws_key={api_key}'

    # Send the POST request with the modified data
    response = requests.post(create_url, data=modified_xml, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 201:
        # Display success message
        print("The new product has been created successfully.")
    else:
        # Display error message if the request failed
        print(f"Error creating the product: {response.status_code}")
else:
    # Display error message if the request failed
    print(f"Request error: {response.status_code}")
```

can anyone help me i'm novice
sry for my english
i try to see my log but nothing is writing
i use apache in localhost and i'm in ubuntu

Comment: do I have to put all the variables?